# Display numbers in a order using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I tried this code and got the output below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write("<table border='1' width='70%'>");
    for(var a=1;a<=20;a=a+5){
      document.write('<tr>');
      for(var b=a;b<a+5;b++){

          document.write("<td>"+b+"</td>");

      }
      document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write("</table>");

    </script>
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

How can I display the output like this:

```
 1  6 11 16
 2  7 12 17
 3  8 13 18
 4  9 14 19
 5 10 15 20
```

Comment: Never use `document.write()`. Never **ever** use `document.write()` to write partial elements (just the opening or closing tags).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must be try it before you asking, 
this is my solution , you can try this code or making your own code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write("<table border='1' width='70%'>");

//  I made a condition where a <= 5. because there are 5 columns needed right there.

for(var a=1;a<=5;a++){
  document.write('<tr>');

  // on this loop I made a condition where b <= 20 and the increment b+=5 because every rows show a number multiple 5 start from "a" value to 20

  for(var b=a;b<=20;b+=5){

      document.write("<td>"+b+"</td>");

  }
  document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

the description on the script . I'm not good at explaining it, sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing

Comment: Giving the OP a solution without explaining what was wrong is not going to actually help the OP develop as a programmer.

Comment: yeah you are right , sorry my bad. let me change my answer